# Visual Studio 2008 C++ Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker

I'm trying to write a program to calculate the quadratic formula.  When I run it, I get 2 error messages:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

this is after I changed the last line of code from 
...:

```
<< danswer1, danswer2 >>
```

to

```
<< danswer1 << "," << danswer2 <<
```

Before I made that change I got 2 compiler errors: C2563 and C2568.
On a friend's computer the program worked perfectly.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is your project a Win32 Console Application or a Win32 Application? If you are using regular main(int argc, char** argv), then make sure your app is a console app.

Answer (score 1):

You can change to a console app by going to the Project **Properties**, **Configuration Properties**, **Linker**, **System** editor. You can then switch your **SubSystem** from Windows to Console (or vice-versa). Make sure to do this for both your Debug and Release configurations.